# R: Hypothesis testing for arima time series object

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to perform a hypothesis test for an arima forecast, and I haven't been able to find resources for it. Below is a reproducible example of my data. I'm using a zoo time series because my frequency is weekdays only.

The hypothesis test I'd like to perform is:

**H1**: The forecasted value is greater than a specified value which I'd provide,

**H0**: There is no difference in values.

```
library(timeDate)
library(forecast)
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(12345)

dates=timeSequence('2017-09-01','2017-09-08')
dates=dates[isWeekday(dates)]%>%as.character()%>%as.POSIXct()
# Need to drop the timeDate class

values=rnorm(n=6,mean=12500,sd=500)

cumValues=cumsum(values)

zooObj=zoo(cumValues,dates)

arimaModel=auto.arima(zooObj)
```

So for this data, the predicted next value is:

```
 > forecast(arimaModel,h=1)
       Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
1504929600       83612.53 78117.67 89107.39 75208.87 92016.19
```

I'd like to hypothesis test the probability that the next value is greater than 83,000.

Comment: Hello.  I don't know that there is such a test in the literature; however, I believe P(n+1)>83,000 could be solved through a brute force numerical approach.  Would that be helpful to you?  My initial guess would be that it would be just over 0.5 (as 83,000 is just under the point estimate).

Comment: I suppose I can hack together a solution where I make a big set of error bands and read across the data frame to find a close value.

I really feel like there should be a way to do this. Maybe I'll dip into the source code for forecasting arima models. If it's able to give confidence intervals, it should be possible to do hypothesis tests.